# Assign a Range of Numbers to a Single Key with Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, range

I was working on a dictionary, but I came up with an issue. And the issue is, I want to be able to use more than 1 number in order to reference a key in a dictionary.

For example, I want the range of numbers between 1 and 5 to be all assigned to, let's say, "apple". So I came up with this:

```
my_dict['apple'] = range(1,5)
```

At the program's current state, its far from being able to run, so testing is an issue, but I do not receive any issues from my editor. I was just wondering, is this the correct way to go about this? Or is there a better way?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

A little more info: I want to make a random integer with the `randint` function. Then, after Python has generated that number, I want to use it to call for the key assigned to the value of the random integer. Thing is, I want to make some things more common than others, so I want to make the range of numbers I can call it with larger so the chance of the key coming up becomes likelier. Sorry if it doesn't make much sense, but at the current state, I really don't even have code to show what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the dictionary backwards. If you want to be able to recall, e.g., `'apple'` with any of the numbers 1-5, you'd need the numbers to be the *keys*, not the *values*.

```
for i in range(1,6):  # range(a,b) gives [a,b)
    my_dict[i] = 'apple'
```

etc. Then, `my_dict[4] == 'apple'` and the same is true for the other values in the range.

This can create very large dictionaries with many copies of the same value.

Alternately, you *can* use `range` objects as dictionary keys, but the testing will be a bit more cumbersome unless you create your own class.

```
my_dict[range(1,6)] = 'apple'
n = random.randint(1, 5)

for key in my_dict:
    if n in key:
        print(my_dict[key])
```

...prints `apple`.

Answer (score 0):

The value in a dictionary can be *any* arbitrary object. Whether it makes sense to use a given type or structure as a value only makes sense in the context of the complete script, so it is impossible to tell you whether it is the correct solution with the given information.

Comment: OK, heres a little more info about what I'm doing: I want to make a random integer with the `randint` function. Then, after Python has generated that number, I want to use it to call for the key assigned to the value of the random integer. Thing is, I want to make some things more common than others, so I want to make the range of numbers I can call it with larger so the chance of the key coming up becomes likelier. Sorry if it doesn't make much sense, but at the current state, I really don't even have code to show what I'm trying to accomplish.